# Uploading svg to WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to find a way to upload SVG files to WP image library. Every time I try it says

> 'you are not allowed to upload files of this type for security reasons'

I've tried two different plugins.

Nothing is working.

Comment: Actually this is a proper question and does not need more debugging details since this is the default Wordpress behaviour that that can be altered using filters as shown below.

Answer (score 2):

You can allow new file extensions in your library by modifying the file **functions.php** in **theme** folder (or your own custom plugin) in wordpress. Add the follwoing codes to **functions.php** to allow **SVG** mime in library:

```
function my_own_mime_types( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_own_mime_types' );
```

**Edit After all comments:**

Wordpress checks if the filetype is matching the file content. So if you the problem presists, check the file content and make sure that you are uploading a real SVG file with valid xml content.

Comment: Thanks. Can I add it anywhere?

Comment: Yes it should work anywhere in `functions.php`. @Nac. For maintenance purposes I always add my own codes at the end of files.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. It still says, `you are not allowed to upload this file type for security reasons`

Comment: I thought this answer should work so I tried it and was totally stunned that it didn't. After reading the source code of the function wp_check_filetype_and_ext() and running it in the debugger I found the problem. WordPress is being very careful and tries to see that the mime type matches the content of the file. It uses PHP's finfo_file( finfo_open( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE ), $file ) to determine the mime type from the file content. Unfortunately this determines the mime type to be 'text/html'.

Comment: Since, it doesn't match 'image/svg' WordPress sees this as a security problem and rejects the upload. So you need to change "$mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'" to "$mimes['svg'] = 'text/html'". If you think about this svg are not really image resources from the point of view of HTML, i.e. it is not used as the src parameter of an HTML img element.

Comment: @Ali Sheikhpour your original answer is correct "$mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';" works on a valid svg file. I unfortunately was not using a valid svg file in my tests. Romel Indemne is right you need to make sure you have a valid svg file.

Comment: You should re-edit your answer and remove "$mimes['svg'] = 'text/html'" and maybe add a comment that if this does not work you should check that you have a valid svg file.

Answer (score 2):

put  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>` before `<svg>` tag, like this [SVG code to update before uploading to wordpress Media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7I8f.png)

Comment: that works indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure @magenta's answer will work. I encountered this problem and found out that the error is in the svg. You might need to sanitize your SVG before you upload.

[sanitize svg here](http://svg.enshrined.co.uk/)

Paste the code of your svg, click sanitize and copy the sanitized version to your file and then upload to wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After checking it turns out I didn't have a valid svg file - not all files with an svg extension are valid svg file.